# Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier ... when using multiple storyboard files

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I used to have all my view controllers in the same storyboard, I decided that makes sense to split up the storyboards so I created a new storyboard file `New File -> User Interface -> StoryBoard`, cut all the controllers related with the user management (Login, register, password recover ...) and pasted them in the new file

Now when I call `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")` it crashes with the following error:

```
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x...>) doesn't contain a view 
            controller with identifier 'LoginViewController''
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Did you instantiate the new storyboard? `let storyboard2 = UIStoryboard(name: ..., bundle: ...)`

Comment: That was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the new storyboard instance, and get the LoginViewController StoryboardId

```
//Here, create an instance of the second storyboard excluding the extension(.storyboard), 
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryBoard", bundle: nil) 

//Here instantiate view controller with the storyboard instance, 
//Before that create a storyboardId for the corresponding view controller.
var loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as LoginViewController

//Here, the storyboard identifier is "loginViewController" which is created in the respective view controller's "Identity" inspector
```

Hope this helps, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 16):

I think your problem is here, navigate to the Main.storyBoard after that click on your viewController which you want to initiate after that give it to the identifier here:

[image]

May be this will help you.